# Time dilation for increasing industrial output and life expectancy

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

I'd like to know an answer to a more practical question.
Let us assume that there are two factories where people produce shawls with the equal speed and use the equal amount of raw material.

Factory A is located on Earth and factory B is in the spaceship that moves with the speed of 280,000 km/s.

My question one is: if both factories started to produce shawls at the same time, would factory B produce the maximum amount of shawls faster, if they return to Earth once they are done?
Would people from factory B be also younger than people from factory A?

And what if humanity will live on a giant spaceship that travels with the same, 280,000 km/s speed? Would they be able to live twice as long than on Earth and actually do twice as many things while on Earth?

Sending my gratitude in advance.

Comment: This appears to be the twin paradox in a thin disguise

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that relativistic time dilation *slows* things. Unfortunately the fast moving factory will produce less shawls than the Earth factory (just $\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ as many). The employees will be younger than their twins on Earth though.